# S3 Access Denied even when running the CDK with AdministratorAccess

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, aws-cdk

I am getting below error, as those are in AWS Console, please find the attached screenshots:

[image]

[image]

I was just cloning this project https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dev-hour-backend and trying it out.

Also I have bootstrap using

```
cdk bootstrap \
  --cloudformation-execution-policies arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess
```

Comment: Without knowing too much about the source code, these errors are usually coming from cloudformation when s3 assets are defined in the template (e.g. a lambda, nested stack) and the bucket in which these assets reside are not accessible.  S3 is particularly annoying since it could be related to the access policy, kms key policy, or scp's.. maybe you can check the synthesized template for s3 references and check those buckets for their bucket policy and kms keys.

Comment: What is your codepipeline role?

Comment: @Marcin apart from the permission set during the CDK deploy i.e. AdminAccess I have not set any seperate role for Pipeline.